# Examples of topological spaces $X, Y$ with opposing continuous bijections $f: X \rightleftarrows Y: g$ with non-isomorphic $\pi_1$

Tags: algebraic-topology

The existence of continuous bijections $f: X\rightleftarrows Y: g$ doesn't necessarily imply that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, if $f$ and $g$ aren't inverses of each other. I'm interested in examples of pairs of spaces that have distinct $\pi_1$ (or even distinct homology groups) where such continuous bijections exist in both direction.

Comment: John Palmieri's answer is terrific, and makes me curious if we could find a path-connected example.

Comment: I think that if we adjoin countably math paths to $X$ to get a space $\tilde{X}= ...---[0, 1)^2 --- [0, 1)^2 --- S^1\times [0, 1) --- (S^1)^2 --- (S^1)^2 ---...$ (and do the same thing to obtain $\tilde{Y}$ from $Y$), then extending the continuous bijections $X \rightleftarrows Y$ to continuous bijections $\tilde{X} \rightleftarrows \tilde{Y}$ in the obvious way gives us a path-connected example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lovely answer at https://mathoverflow.net/a/251028/4194 should work: $X$ is the disjoint union of

- countably many copies of $[0,1) \times [0,1)$
- a single copy of $S^1 \times [0,1)$
- countably many copies of $S^1 \times S^1$

and $Y$ is the disjoint union of

- countably many copies of $[0,1) \times [0,1)$
- countably many copies of $S^1 \times S^1$

The post describes bijections in each direction, the nontrivial parts of which are based on the standard example of the continuous bijection $[0,1) \to S^1$.

There is a choice of basepoint for $X$ for which the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$, but there is no such choice for $Y$.